# jQuery - if div is at top of window, add class/style? (sticky banner)

Tags: jquery

So I've made a sticky banner

**Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zu60j5rr/**

In the example it works fine.  But the site that I want to use it on has a top nav that doesn't quite render the same across different browsers.  So I can't rely on "top" to work as it should across all browsers

So what I'm wondering is.  Is there any way I can add a statement of something like, if the div hit the top of the window - Add style to fix the position?  And then if it's scrolled back, remove the style?

here's what I currently have, as fiddled:

```
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#stickyBanner').css({position: "fixed", top: "0px"});
        } else {
            $('#stickyBanner').css({position: "relative", top: "0px"});
        }
    });
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change your script a little bit so it can check if the offset top value of the sticky nav is bigger or equal to the value of the window scrollTop. Basically if they are the same / equal the element is at top of the window :)

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/zu60j5rr/1/

```
var stickyTop = $('#stickyBanner').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('#stickyBanner').css({position: "fixed", top: "0px"});
        } else {
            $('#stickyBanner').css({position: "relative", top: "0px"});
        }
    });
```